# Access site or post variables inside a jekyll converter

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

In liquid, I can access, say, `{{ post.title }}` or any variables that are defined in the markdown. How can I get at the equivalent of `{{ post.title }}` from a converter or a generator or a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### from a converter

No way. They are just converting content to hmtl.

#### from a generator

In the `Generate` method you receive the `site` object, you can then loop in `site.pages` and `site.posts`.

#### from a filter

Depending on what you pass to the filter you can get any page/post variable

```
module Jekyll
  module MyFilters
    def filter_name(page)
      # do whatever with the page variables
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::MyFilters)
```

Example call : `{{ page | filter_name }}`

Comment: Yup. That's it. As a clarifying note to myself, I think a converter should only be dealing with markdown (or markdown-like) elements.